# Data Request: Raw housing stock of particular city

Tags: data-request

I want to get the raw number of units of housing stock that there is in a particular city in month $X$ of year $Y$ (even yearly data would be fine). [This place](http://factfinder.census.gov/faces/tableservices/jsf/pages/productview.xhtml?src=bkmk) shows yearly stock from 2010 onwards. [Here](https://www.census.gov/hhes/www/housing/census/historic/units.html) shows data for every 10 years. This [link](http://www.washingtoncitypaper.com/blogs/housingcomplex/2014/10/24/d-c-s-housing-stock-in-charts/) makes me think there should be more yearly data since this has 2013 data.

Is there anywhere I can find a more comprehensive data set?

Answer (score 1):

There really isn't high-frequency data out there for free, but bi-annual data are available from the Census [American Housing Survey](http://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/ahs/data.2013.html). The survey goes back to 1973, though data at the metropolitan area level don't go back that far. Also, the data are extrapolated from a sample, so caveats apply.